# Installing generic headers without internet in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, dpkg, dependencies

I tried to install generic Linux headers without Internet by downloading them in .deb formats .. Based on the dependencies I installed one by one, then I encountered this `.libc6:i386 depends on libgcc1; and libgcc1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.2.4); .. **these two dependencies are cyclic**` and I am unable to resolve them ..

```
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 180653 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libc6:i386 2.17-0ubuntu5.1 (using libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libc6:i386 ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6:i386:
 **libc6:i386 depends on libgcc1; however:
  Package libgcc1:i386 is not configured yet.**

dpkg: error processing libc6:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:i386
jv@jv-Naruto:~/Downloads/sdsd$ sudo dpkg -i libgcc1_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 180653 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libgcc1:i386 1:4.7.3-1ubuntu1 (using libgcc1_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libgcc1:i386 ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcc1:i386:
 **libgcc1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.2.4); however:
  Package libc6:i386 is not configured yet.**
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Install all deb's at ones (try `ls *.deb` to get the idea of joker `*`)

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.17-0ubuntu5.1_i386.deb libgcc1_4.7.3-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
```

Reference `man dpkg` (`...` means many)

```
-i, --install package-file...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the .deb files for libgcc1 from:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libgcc1

You may or may not be able to get it's dependencies if needed, because not all files in the Ubuntu repos are available through the packages.ubuntu.com site.

Go to the bottom of the page, click i386 or amd64, choose a mirror (they are direct download links to the .deb).